# WinApi: share memory across two processes using VirtualAlloc

Tags: winapi

I’m attempting to allocate some memory which can be shared across two processes using the Win API. I have successfully implemented it using [CreateFileMapping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)/[OpenFileMapping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366791(v=vs.85).aspx) in combination with [MapViewOfFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366761(v=vs.85).aspx). However, I require the base address to be consistent across the two processes which it is not given with named shared memory. Thus, I tried to use [VirtualAlloc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887(v=vs.85).aspx) to create the memory in the first process at a specific address the following:

```
VirtualAlloc((void*)0x80000000LL, 
             65536, 
             MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, 
             PAGE_READWRITE);
```

This doesn’t report any errors and the allocated memory is useable. Yet, if I try to access the memory at this specific location in the second process:

```
char c = *((const char*)0x80000000LL);
```

it yields "Attempt to access invalid address". Is there a function which I need to call in the second/first process to make the memory region read/writeable or change the permission?

Comment: This isn't going to work out. What made you think you have to do it like this?

Comment: Check out the following [code project article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366890(v=vs.85).aspx)

This article goes over reading/writing but not allocating. For allocating you will need to call VirtualAllocEx (described in this [msdn article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366890(v=vs.85).aspx))

Comment: Only Windows 95/98/ME will let you allocate in one process and share it with everyone like that, NT requires that you allocate or map in every process.

Comment: And note that file mapping does give you the option of specifying a base address (you then have to check that the desired address was in fact used). But if file mapping couldn't use the address VirtualAlloc wouldn't help anyway.

Comment: "*However, I require the base address to be consistent across the two processes which it is not given with named shared memory*" - you can use `MapViewOfFileEx()`, which has an `lpBaseAddress` parameter for that exact purpose. But really, this is not necessary, since each process must map its own view of the shared file mapping object, so the base address within each process DOES NOT need to be the same. Use consistent offsets to access specific data within each view.

Comment: This appears to be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). At a guess your real problem is likely, how to properly serialize data. If this is not the case, please explain, why you need the memory sections to be at the same address in both processes.